# ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker doesn't work with Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using [ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker](https://github.com/atais/ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker) in angular app. It works with Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4 Alpha 5, but only an empty popup is shown for Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6.

[Working Sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/bUVVQu).
If you'll change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

in index.html to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: You can try https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker for a datepicker that works with Bootstrap 4 CSS and Angular.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource, you are right, it works. But I need the datetimepicker. ng-bootstrap provides datepicker and timepicker separately. ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker is what I really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solution](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1996) + it's necessary to change glyphicon icons with font awesome icons, because glyphicon icons have been removed from bootstrap 4.